# Uploading xml to windows phone 8 VB

Tags: vba, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

```
    `Dim medium As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim data_xml = XElement.Load("Assets\Manager.xml")

    'next quaries the xml for desired attributes
    Dim query = From DataTable1 In data_xml.Descendants("DataTable1")
                Where (DataTable1.Attribute("Medium").Value = medium)
                Select Uname = DataTable1.Attribute("Username").Value

    For Each result In query
    'displays results to textbox
        TextBox2.Text = result
    Next
```

I try to use this code to read from an xml file in the assets but the file does not seem to exist

At the declaration of the `xelement.load("Assets\Manager.xml")` I get this error

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\d5d3a1e7-56d7-477c-bcd2-f949f3374de1VS.Debug_AnyCPU.NAME\Assets\Manager.xml'.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to make it work:

- Change Manager.xml `Build action` to Content
- Change `Copy to output directory` to Copy if newer
- Load file using `XElement.Load("Assets/Manager.xml");`

**Edit:**

Ok, since you are not willing to share more of the code even though you ask for help, there's nothing else I can do but put up an example :)

"Software" below, implemented in Visual Basic, reads and displays XML file named Manager.xml, that is set as Content in WP8 project. Working example can be found at https://github.com/mikkoviitala/read-content-xml

[image: imgur]

Comment: Well, thats how you do it. Propably you missed something "too obvious". Share (part of your) project here, as ZIP or on Git and I'm sure it will be sorted out.

Comment: sorry cant it contains information i would rather not disclose, but thank you

Comment: thank you, it just has alot of content for personal usernames and passwords and personal encryption tecniques, i do appriciate